# Find the volume of the solid bounded by the xy plane, the cylinder $x^{2} + y^{2}=4$, and the plane $z+y=4$.

Tags: multiple-integral

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the xy plane, the cylinder $x^{2} + y^{2}=4$, and the plane $z+y=4$.

---

If we draw the graph, then the integral will be calculated should be

$$ \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}} (4-y) \: dy dx $$

This would give the volume of the solid in 1st quadrant which can also be obtained through

$$ \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^{2}}} (4-y) \: dx dy $$

which would be equal to [$4\pi - \frac83$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+_%7B0%7D%5E2%5Cint+_0%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B4-y%5E2%7D%7D%5Cleft(4-y%5Cright)dxdy%5C:%5C:). Both the above equations give the [same result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+_%7B0%7D%5E2%5Cint+_0%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B4-x%5E2%7D%7D%5Cleft(4-y%5Cright)dydx%5C:%5C:).

But if we try to find the volume of the entire solid formed by the three curves, then the results from the above equations(after changing the limits appropriately) don't match.
[$$ \int_{-2}^{2} 2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^{2}}} (4-y) \: dy dx = 2(8\pi-\frac{16}{3})$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Cint+_%7B-2%7D%5E%7B2%7D%5Cint+_0%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B4-x%5E2%7D%7D%5Cleft(4-y%5Cright)dydx)
[$$ \int_{-2}^{2} 2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-y^{2}}} (4-y) \: dx dy = 16\pi$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Cint+_%7B-2%7D%5E%7B2%7D%5Cint+_0%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B4-y%5E2%7D%7D%5Cleft(4-y%5Cright)dxdy)

why the results of the these two equations don't match? Is there some problem with the limits I've set or something else? Please help

PS: There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730720/find-the-volume-of-the-solid-in-the-firsr-quadrant-bounded-by-the-coordinate-pla?rq=1), but my query is different.

Answer (score 1):

The limits of the second integral are wrong. It should be $$2\int_0^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{4-y^{2}}} (4-y) \: dx\ dy=4\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-y^{2}}} (4-y) \: dx\ dy$$
The answers match.